# Is there any package like cls-rtracer to log with request id in sails.js?

Tags: sails.js

I am using SailsJS to develop my web server, I found the logs are mixed with different request and it is difficult to unique them. Is there any package like cls-rtracer in SailsJS framework?

Answer (score 0):

You should use any of them

```
sails.log.info("Log Info");
sails.log.debug("Log Debug");
sails.log.warn("Log Warn");
sails.log.error("Log Error");
```

And you will see logs like below, I hope this is enough to differentiate logs.

[image]